# is there a way to create shortcuts for a list of windows commands?

Tags: command-line

Not very sure if this is the right way of asking, but I was wondering if it is at all possible to "bunch/combine" these commands:

```
cd %webapps%
cls
mvn clean install
copy etc\environment\dev\yao\env.conf.bat webapps-dist\target\classes
yes
cd %jboss%
run.bat -c server -b 0.0.0.0
shutdown.bat -S
```

into ONE command like: %runserver% or something like that?

Also, is there a way to get rid of the prompt when I try to copy a file?

I literally do this every time I reinstall my apps, so a shortcut would be amazing.
I already just copy and paste these commands, but I'm lazy so I want shorter commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running these commands from the same location, you can make a batch file and just run the batch file.

Comment: what do you mean changes directory?  If you mean the location you are trying to run the script from, then yes you are stuck.  You can only run the batch from the directory that it lives in.  If you want to be able to use that batch file from any directory, I think you can add the directory it is in into your "Path" environment variable.